# Resolution images in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a galary with this code :

```
.gallery {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

    .gallery > div {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
    }

        .gallery > div > img {
            display: block;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            transition: .1s transform;
            transform: translateZ(0);
        }

        .gallery > div:hover {
            z-index: 1;
        }

            .gallery > div:hover > img {
                transform: scale(2.5,2.5);
                transition: .3s transform;
            }

.cf:before, .cf:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

This website : gtmetrix.com tell me i need to resize the images from 4128x2322 to 150px-150px but in  `.gallery > div > img` i have `height: 150px` and `width: 150px;`.

How can I reduce the quality?
I want more speed on my website.

Comment: You say your website is loading "hard" and your image is loading "hard". I am guessiing English is not your first language, but this term "hard" does not make any sense. Can you please try to explain better what you mean by "hard"?

Comment: @jsherk Is loading so slowly. I host right now on 000webhost.com and is same.

Comment: this is not a css issue. This is your actual images files which are too high resolution / large. You need to preprocess / resize them on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your question was edited and now it is "how to reduce the size of my images? I tried via CSS but its still slow.", is that right?

Well, you tried reducing the size via css, but CSS just defines how stuff is *displayed*. The client will still have to download the whole, large 4128x2322 picture first and then resize it to 150x150 to display it on the screen.

What you need to do is change the actual source image that is on your server. 4128x2322 is definitely a very large resolution for a website. I don't know where your site or the image is hosted, but basically you need to open the image file wherever it is hosted and edit the image to reduce its size, e.g. via GIMP.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have hosted it, try [this site](http://gtmetrix.com)

Comment: Thanks. This website show me why is loading so slowly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you didn't understand the real problem. To make the images load faster you need to reduce the image *file* size, not the image *display* size.

I mean, when you change the size on CSS you only change the size of the image in the screen, but in order to display ot the browser need to download the full file and the resize it to the final size.

In your case the image size is 4128x2322 (about 12 megapixel), which is way too big. You need to use an image editor to reduce the image size, there are several free like [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.net/) or [Paint.net](https://www.getpaint.net/)